# After alignment of the table overflow isn't working? couldn't figure out why?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

this is my css there are other elements also which are not related I think
and i am using the below css to align the table to the center of the screen its fine untill the table has 12 or 13 rows after that it exceeds the screen i want it to scroll after it exceed the limit of the screen
before that it keeps expanding from the center
css

```
      .toAlignTable {
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 40px 30px 30px 30px;
      position: absloute;
      top: 48%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 750px;
      height: auto;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms, box-shadow 300ms;
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 300ms, box-shadow 300ms;
      transition: transform 300ms, box-shadow 300ms;
      box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px rgba(2, 128, 144, 0.2);
    }
```

html table

```
  <table class="highlight centered responsive-table toaligntable" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="border-top-left-radius: 10px;">S.No.</th>
        <th>Account name</th>
        <th style="border-top-right-radius: 10px;">Login</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="searchResultsBody"  style="font-size: 120%;">

    </tbody>
  </table>

    <template id="populateTemplate">
        <tr style="font-weight: 180;height:auto;">
            <td style="background-color: #c5cbce;" class="s_num"  scope="row"></td>
            <td style="background-color: #dddddd;" class="collection_acc" scope="row"></td>
            <td><button class="waves-effect waves-light roundeed blue-grey btn access_btn">access</button></td>
        </tr>
    </template>
```

javaScript

```
var resultsArray = [
    [
        1,
        "FIRST ACCOUNT",
        "PRIMARY"
    ],
    [
        2,
        "SECOND ACCOUNT",
        "PRIMARY"
    ],
    [
        3,
        "THIRD ACCOUNT",
        "SECONDARY"
    ],
.
.
.
     [
        15,
        "fifteen ACCOUNT",
        "SECONDARY"
    ]
]

    var searchResultsBox= document.getElementById("searchResultsBody");
    var templateBox= document.getElementById("populateTemplate");
    var template = templateBox.content;

    searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";

    resultsArray.forEach(function(r){

        var row = template.cloneNode(true);

        row.querySelector(".s_num").textContent = r[0];
        row.querySelector(".collection_acc").textContent = r[1];
        row.querySelector(".access_btn").dataset.clientID = r[0];

        searchResultsBox.appendChild(row);

    });
```

when there are only a few rows it keeps expanding but then
[image]
after having more than 15 rows it exceeds the screen
[image]

I want the table to have scroll when the table exceeds the limit in y-axix

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
overflow:auto;
max-height: 30rem; //or something that seems reasonable
```

Try it in your css for .toAlignTable

If that doesn't work, instead wrap your table in a div and apply the css there, including moving the absolute positon /offset stuff (sorry I'm on phone, can't check)

For something to scroll a parent
needs to have a smaller height than the content, and the `overflow` property of the parent must allow for scrolling, instead of hiding it (`overflow:hidden`)

The default is `overflow:visible`, which will show the content, and you haven't set a max height of the container